# Cannot cast string to generic C# type

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.7.2

I want to return a string from a method which returns a generic type. How can I do this?

This is my method (abridged):

```
public async Task<(bool success, TResponse)> SendRequest<TResponse>(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // return success and generic content
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content));
}
```

The problem here is that `content` might contain no JSON, so we pass `TResponse` as `string`. This means the we want to detect that `TResponse` is a string and just do a plain return, eg:

```
if (typeof(TResponse) == typeof(String))
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, content);
else
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content));
```

However, this has a build-time error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'TResponse'
```

So, I'm doing this, which appears to work but smells bad:

```
if (typeof(TResponse) == typeof(String))
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, (TResponse)((object)content));
else
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content));
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: Put the `typeof(TResponse) == typeof(String)` case in a separate, non-generic method, that returns `Task<(bool success, string)>`. Generic methods are supposed to be generic, and not care about its what their type parameters really are.

Comment: I can see making allowances for careful exceptions to that rule. For example, `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` have a special case where `T` is `char` in their `ToString` implementations. They return a string with those `char`s instead of the type name. Returning the raw response as a string when `TResponse` is `string` isn't the worst violation of the rule, although it does preclude deserialization of a `string` JSON token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the infamous "cast via `object`" trick (note that for value types compiler/runtime is smart enough to not do actual boxing):

```cs
if (typeof(TResponse) == typeof(string))
    return (true, (TResponse)(object)content);
```

There is community request to allow "bridging" of the generic type in C# - see for example [this github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6308), but for now for this use case the aforementioned approach is the possible workaround.

Also you can create a non-generic overload for this specific use case (note that in theory you might actually want to use `Deserialize` if API returns double encoded strings):

```cs
public async Task<(bool success, string content)> SendRequest(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your function returns a `(bool, TResponse)`, you can't return a `(bool, string)`. You could make something like a wrapper object that contains the `bool`, the `TResponse` and the `string`, but you can't just return a string instead of whatever TResponse will be

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is expecting you to return a `TResponse`, so you can't just return a `string`. Here are just a few possibilities for working around this.

## #1: Default Object

You can return a default response object in the case that the response isn't valid JSON. The simplest way to do this is with polymorphism to make a "return package" object with an empty state option.

```cs
public class Response<T>
{
    // ...
}

public class EmptyResponse<T> : BaseResponse<T> {}

public class DataResponse<T> : BaseResponse<T>
{
    T Data { get; private set; }

    Response(T data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task<(bool success, Response<TResponse>)> SendRequest<TResponse>(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (/* response is JSON */)
        return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, new DataResponse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content)));
    else 
        return (false, new EmptyResponse<TResponse>());
}
```

```cs
var (success, response) = await SendRequest<...>(...);
if (response is DataResponse<...>)
{
    ...
}
```

## #2: Either Monad

To greatly oversimplify it, the [`Either` monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/05/09/an-either-monad/) is a pattern that allows a response to be one of two possibilities. In practice for this application, this is similar to option #1 but in a more generalized way. (It's sort of a type union for languages that don't natively support type unions.)

(Note that this is a bare minimum implementation. A proper `Either` monad type would include many other features, such as the ability to `Map` the data to other types.)

```cs
public abstract class Either<TLeft, TRight>
{
    public abstract bool IsLeft { get; }
    public abstract bool IsRight { get; }
    
    public abstract TLeft UnwrapLeft();
    public abstract TRight UnwrapRight();
}

public class Left<TLeft, TRight> : Either<TLeft, TRight>
{
    private TLeft data;
    
    public Left(TLeft data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override bool IsLeft { get => true; }
    public override bool IsRight { get => false; }
    
    public override TLeft UnwrapLeft()
    {
        return data;
    }
    
    public override TRight UnwrapRight()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Monad is not a Right");
    }
}

public class Right<TLeft, TRight> : Either<TLeft, TRight>
{
    private TRight data;
    
    public Right(TRight data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override bool IsLeft { get => false; }
    public override bool IsRight { get => true; }
    
    public override TLeft UnwrapLeft()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Monad is not a Left");
    }
    
    public override TRight UnwrapRight()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task<(bool success, Either<Response<TResponse>, string>)> SendRequest<TResponse>(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (/* response is JSON */)
        return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, new Left<Response<TResponse>, string>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content)));
    else 
        return (false, new Right<Response<TResponse>, string>(content));
}
```

```cs
var (success, response) = await SendRequest<...>(...);
if (request.IsLeft())
{
    var obj = request.UnwrapLeft();
    ...
}
```

## #3: Raw String

A third option is to just return the raw content string and let the caller worry about deserialization. This could be preferable to your current approach as it allows your HTTP handler to be more self-contained and purposeful. Depending on your setup, though, this might not be advisable as it could result in messy code.

```cs
public async Task<(bool success, string content)> SendRequest(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, content);
}
```

```cs
var (success, content) = await SendRequest(...);
if (success)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<...>(content);
    ...
}
```

## #4: Nullable

More of an honorable mention since resorting to null in general isn't exactly good practice, but you could always just add a return for the raw content and set the deserialized response to null if the content isn't serializable JSON:

```cs
public async Task<(bool success, string content, TResponse?)> SendRequest<TResponse>(...)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    TResponse? data = null;

    if (/* response is JSON */)
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);

    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode, content, data);
}
```

Comment: For discriminated unions (similar to Either Monad), check out the [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) package.

Comment: @Hank That's an excellent package for this use case, though I would add the caveat that unless OP wants to fully embrace that aspect of the functional programming style (with discriminated unions, matching, etc.), it would likely be overkill.

Comment: Any particular reason to make third option generic?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, it's a very important reason, namely where I copy-pasted code without removing the redundant bits. :|

Comment: @Abion47 yep, that was my theory)